# How to calculate system response with input given?

Tags: signal-processing

i am trying to understand how system responses and impulse responses work. 
Given that i have a system described by the following expression:

$y(n) = 3x(n+2) + 2x(n) - 4x(n-2)$

I want to calculate the system response when the signal x(n) is:

1. $x(n) = 2$, if $n = 0,1$
2. $x(n) = -3$, if $n = -2$
3. $x(n) = 0$, otherwise

Can anyone explain how to achieve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Just replace $n=0$ in the system equation to obtain $y(0)$. Do this for all $n$ to obtain $y(n)$.

Comment: @Stelios would you mind explaining what it means x(n) = 2, if n=0,1 then? you're saying i need to substitute n with 0, so i would get y(0) = 14x; then what would x(n) = 2 mean? This is the point i don't understand! Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: $y(0)=3x(0+2)+2x(0)-4x(0-2)=3x(2)+2x(0)-4x(-2)$

Comment: @Stelios sorry my bad i might have misinterpreted everything!!! thank you!